# EF Core 2.2 spatial type can't be added to db migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, spatial, ef-core-2.2

I'm trying to build a database with a spatial object using EF core 2.2, and i'm getting a problem with trying to create the database migrations.  using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/spatial , specifically:

```
class Country
{
    public int CountryID { get; set; }

    public string CountryName { get; set; }

    // Database includes both Polygon and MultiPolygon values
    public IGeometry Border { get; set; }
}
```

if i try to create a migration with this i get the following error:

> The property 'Country.Border' is of an interface type ('IGeometry').
>   If it is a navigation property manually configure the relationship for
>   this property by casting it to a mapped entity type, otherwise ignore
>   the property using the NotMappedAttribute or
>   'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

similarly if i change it to a Geometry type instead, i get:

> The property 'Geometry.UserData' could not be mapped, because it is of
>   type 'object' which is not a supported primitive type or a valid
>   entity type. Either explicitly map this property, or ignore it using
>   the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in
>   'OnModelCreating'.

I don't know ahead of time if my object is going to be a Point or a Line or Polygon, so it has to be generic.  how do i represent that in my structure?  Additionally i've seen some places say i need to add the following code:

```
public class MyDBContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<MyDBContext>
    {

        public MyDBContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDBContext>();
            builder.UseSqlServer(cnnString, x => x.UseNetTopologySuite());
            return new MyDBContext(builder.Options);
        }
   }
```

but i get the error:

> 'SqlServerDbContextOptionsBuilder' does not contain a definition for
>   'UseNetTopologySuite' and no accessible extension method
>   'UseNetTopologySuite' accepting a first argument of type
>   'SqlServerDbContextOptionsBuilder' could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?)

even though i have the nuget package installed

Answer (score 25, accepted):

1. Install the relevant NetTopologySuite package, it [depends](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/spatial) on the database you are using, for example you are using SqlServer so you need to install this NuGet package:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.NetTopologySuite
> 2) Configure your database to use NetTopologySuite (the code to edit is normally in `StartUp.ConfigureServices()`). Just add `, x => x.UseNetTopologySuite()` inside the `options.UseSqlServer` brackets

so it looks like this:

```
services.AddDbContext<ManagerContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(
        Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
        x => x.UseNetTopologySuite()
    )
);
```

I did not have to add a `using` to the file because I already had referenced, FYI it would be `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` if you needed it.

If you get a reference error even after installing the NuGet package go to Manage NuGet Package and check if it's on the installed list and if it is Clean & Rebuild your solution and restart visual studio it might help.

Comment: that's the same link i provided above, it's what made me aware of the line, but it doesn't work.  I have builder.UseSqlServer(cnnString, x => x.UseNetTopologySuite()); , but i get told it can't find that reference.  yes i've added the nuget package

Comment: yeah, thanks for looking but I've done all that.  your edit assumes i'm using dbContext the same as you, and i'm not.  I have a class that inherits from idesigntimedbcontextfactory, like : public class MyDBContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<MyDBContext>.  In there i use the CreateDBContext method.  it should work the same, but it doesn't look the same.  see my edited question

Comment: Ugh, my bad, you're right.  I was focusing on Install-Package NetTopologySuite instead of the EFCore one you mentioned above.

Comment: I'd just like to add for others that you also need to install the correct _version_ of the package based on the version of EF Core you're using.

Comment: As an additional note: if you are using the design factory pattern you need to add 'UseNetTolopogySuite()' there as well.