# How to map a Point in the entity framework?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, spatial

I am developing an API in the .net core and using the Framework entity.

My bank already existed and in one of the tables I have a Point type field to store coordinates (Spatials).

I'm not using any automatic approach (Ex: code First, DataBase First ...), I am modeling my classes myself.

To map this Point field I did it as in primitive types, I believe to be wrong, and I'm getting an error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The property 'Address.LatLong'
>   could not be mapped, because it is of type 'Point' which is not a
>   supported primitive type or a valid entity type. Either explicitly map
>   this property, or ignore it using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by
>   using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.'

```
public class Address:BaseModel
    {

        [Required]
        [StringLength(30)]
        public string Street { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Number { get; set; }

        [StringLength(45)]
        public string Observation { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(20)]
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(nameof(City))]
        [Required]
        public int CityId { get; set; }
        public virtual City City { get; set; }

        public Point LatLong { get; set; } //this is the field

    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EF Core 2.2 spatial type can't be added to db migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54792840/ef-core-2-2-spatial-type-cant-be-added-to-db-migration)

Answer (score -1):

if you wanna use that point for other address , so u should add something like this to your point Class :

```
public virtual ICollection<Address> Address{ get; set; }
```

and if you dont wanna use that point for another adress , u can bring Lat and Long to your adress class.

by the way i think add this `public virtual ICollection<Address> Address{ get; set; }` should fix your problem